# Call .js function in another.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I have...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="xpath.js"></script>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!-- some html code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("body").click(function(event){
       console.log(event.target);
       //call xpath.js (getxpath(event.target))
   });
});
```

**xpath.js**

[here](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js) stored locally

**How do I achieve this..?**

Comment: ok...what changes are required in xpath.js...can you help...?

Comment: @blex I have modified as follows...but it is returning me list of functions...

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/HpfD9iuC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Accessing functions from another file

Code separation between files does not matter (You could pack them all in a single file without any problem). Execution order and scopes do. All scripts loaded on a web page share a same global scope, which is `window`, and can add variables to it.

Most libraries do this so you can access them (jQuery creates a global `$` variable, for example, and you can use it anywhere).

Your *Xpath* script, however, does not, because it's not meant to be directly embedded into a webpage. It's part of a Firefox addon. So in order to make it accessible, you need to modify it.

### Modifying xpath.js

At the beginning, change this:

```
define([
    "firebug/lib/string"
],
function(Str) {
```

... to this:

```
window.Xpath = new (function(Str) {
```

And at the end, change this:

```
});
```

... to this:

```
})();
```

### Using it

Now that you did this, you have a global `Xpath` Object that you can access like this:

```
$(function() {
   $("body").click(function(event){
       console.log(Xpath.getElementXPath(event.target));
   });
});
```